# AMPscript RegExMatch on whole words?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this pattern that will find specific characters, but what if I wanted to find whole words? I know I need word boundaries, and/or lookarounds, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

This pattern looks for specific characters:

```
%%[

set @pattern = "[^(a|b|c|,|\s)]+"
set @str = "a, b, c, x"
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @pattern, 0)

if empty(@result) then 

   /* do nothing */

else

  RaiseError('Unknown value submitted',true)

endif

]%%
```

But if I wanted to do something like

```
%%[

set @pattern = "[^(dog|cat|bird|,|\s)]+" /* This pattern is incorrect to check for whole words */
set @str = "dog, cat, bird, giraffe, abcbirdxyz"
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @pattern, 0)

if empty(@result) then 

   /* do nothing */

else

  RaiseError('Unknown value submitted',true)

endif

]%%
```

My values should be `giraffe` and `abcbirdxyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to find any words, except "dog", "cat" or "bird" in your string, you could use a regular expression along these lines:

```
\b(?!(dog|cat|bird))\w+
```

An explanation of the regular expression above can be found at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/P4gef0/3).

```
%%[
set @pattern = "\b(?!(dog|cat|bird))\w+"
set @str = "dog, cat, bird, giraffe, abcbirdxyz"
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @pattern, 0)

if empty(@result) then
    ]%%No Match%%[
else
    ]%%Match%%[
endif
]%%
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much!